# How to filter text in Scala SQL context data frame based on a list of keywords

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, filter

I have been trying to filter tweets from a SQL dataframe based on selected hashtags.  My code (given below) works when I try to filter tweets for a selected hashtag.

```
dfs.select(dfs("text"))
  .map(r => r.getString(0))
  .filter(_.contains("#tweet_of_interest"))
  .foreach(println)
```

However, when I extend my code to filter tweets based on hashtags stored in a list, I get the following error.

```
dfs.select(dfs("text"))
  .map(r => r.getString(0))
  .filter(hashtag_list.exists(_.contains))
  .foreach(println)
```

> error: missing arguments for method contains in class String; follow
>   this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied
>   function

```
dfs.select(dfs("text"))
  .map(r => r.getString(0))
  .filter(konykeywords.exists(_.contains))
  .foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code:

```
dfs.select(dfs("text")).map(r => r.getString(0)).filter(line => {
  hashtag_list.exists(line.contains)
}).foreach(println)
```

The code you wrote doesn't work like this:

```
hashtag_list.exists(_.contains) // gives the error: missing arguments for method contains in class String; follow this method with '_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function.
```

You have to pass some argument in contains method:

```
hashtag_list.exists(_.contains("somevalue"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also work directly on your DataFrame, using UDF (User Defined Functions) that work on a whole column.

The first step, is to define a function of type `(String => Boolean)`, that receives a tweet and returns true if it should be included in the final DataFrame:

```
def myFunc: (String => Boolean) = { t => hashtag_list.exists(t.contains) }

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val myUDF = udf(myFunc)
```

Then, you can call it directly on the `filter` method of your DataFrame:

```
val filteredDF = dfs.filter(myUDF(col("tweets")))
```

For more information about UDFs, here's a nice article:

http://www.sparktutorials.net/using-sparksql-udfs-to-create-date-times-in-spark-1.5

Comment: Thank you. your solution worked perfectly,  I see that defining as a separate UDF function definitely has several advantages